# Relay Modern- Object passed into QueryRenderer as variable breaks when edited with RefetchContainer

Tags: relayjs, relay

Passing an object into QueryRenderer variable. In the refetch container rendered on success, when anything changes in the object, the container breaks. Also passing an integer as a variable that doesn't break on change via refetch.

i.e.-

```
<QueryRenderer
  query={query}
  variables={
    count: 5, 
    testObject= { 
      something1: { 
        something2: ['something', 'something'] 
      }
    }
  ...
 />

 Refetch container calls via 
 _onRefetch() => {
     const newSearch = {
       something1: {
         something2: ['somethingElse'],
       }
    };
    const refetchVariables = fragmentVariables => ({
      testObject: newSearch,
      count: this.state.currentCount + 10,
    });
   nullthrows(this.props.relay).refetch(
    refetchVariables,
    null);
 }
```

Does relay modern refetch not handle objects, or is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What means `the container breaks`? What is the error message displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up needing to rerender the QR from a parent component when the query level variables changed.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables should be in double braces:

```
<QueryRenderer
  query={query}
  variables={{
    count: 5, 
    testObject: { 
      something1: { 
        something2: ['something', 'something'] 
      }
    }
    ...
  }}
  ...
/>
```

https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/query-renderer.html